# Cookies and ways to read them

Tags: asp.net, web-services, cookies, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

Suppose I created a cookie with one year expiration in domain **abc.com** and now

- I am accessing any page from this domain will the cookie be attached automatically to the Request object.
- I have a webservice in the same domain **abc.com**. Will the web service be able to access the cookie whenever a call is being made from **abc.com** or from **xyz.com**
- Suppose I have an updatepanel and I click a button inside it, will I be able to access the cookie the async method.
- From **xyz.com** can I asynchronously check the presence of this cookie with the help to HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse classes in asp.net. (Because I feel this is also actually sending a request from the browser)
- How actually will the CookieContainer help me in reading cookies from one domain to another domain ?

Thanks,

M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the requests come from a browser, you will get any cookies that your domain is allowed to have.  As far as cookie-sharing, take a look at [this article](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_internet/article.php/c19417/Sharing-Cookies-Across-Domains.htm).